# Guidelines/principles for package and component design

Tags: package, principles, component-design

Alright, our visual studio solution grows big in terms of the number of projects in it.  Except for things that are obvious, I want to check whether the way it is now is what it has to be or we can better reorganize/package it.

Do you know of any good text on guidelines, principles of package and component design that I can reference?  Something in depth, with good analysis, not just tier a, b,c or layer 1, 2, 3, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 28 in the book [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](http://amzn.com/0131857258) by Robert Martin and Micah Martin covers the principles.